# Is electrical resistance always inversely proportional to the cross section in an ohmic conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism

Let's consider an ohmic conductor, for which the Drude model predicts that $\bf{E} = \rho \bf{j}$.
Let $S$ be the cross section at a certain point of the conductor. Then we have $i = \displaystyle \int\limits_S \bf{j}\cdot d\bf{S}$ $= jS$. This yields
\begin{equation} 
\Delta V = El = \rho jl = \left(\rho \frac{l}{S}\right)i = Ri \implies R = \rho \frac{l}{S}
\end{equation}

This derivation relies upon the fact that $\bf{j}$ is constant everywhere. I was wondering if the inverse proportionality between $R$ and $S$ is always true. This is equivalent to asking whether $\bf{E}$ is always constant in an ohmic conductor. 
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

If the cross section of the conductor is uniform over a reasonably long longitudinal distance, yes, the resistance will be inversely proportional to cross-sectional area.

If the cross section is changing dramatically, then the current density in the wider section will not be uniform and you will see some "[crowding resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_crowding)" near where the area changes.

Or if you consider AC currents at high enough frequencies, the *skin effect* leads to the current being concentrated on the outer edges of the conductor. This can lead to the resistance being more proportional to the wire circumference than to the area.